# What is the difference between \leftmark and \rightmark in fancyhdr?

Tags: fancyhdr, definition

I am having a hard time trying to figure out the difference between `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` in [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf). At page 8 of the documentation, it says

> The `\leftmark` contains the Left argument of the *Last* `\markboth` on the page, the `\rightmark` contains the Right argument of the *fiRst* `\markboth` or the only argument of the *fiRst* `\markright` on the page.

However, I could not find the definition of `\markboth`. Could anyone please teach me of the difference or definition of `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`?

My though is, based on my use of `fancyhdr`, `\leftmark` writes chapter number and name if chapters exist, if not, it will write section number and name instead. As for `\rightmark`, it will always write the title one level lower than that of `\leftmark`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Basically these control sequences contain the data that "should" end up on a left page or on a right page. The marking mechanism is intended to provide easy means to change what appears there. `fancyhdr` just positions the content. Most document classes provide defaults (what they think should go on left/right pages).

Comment: Btw: `\markboth:
macro:#1#2->\begingroup \let \label \relax \let \index \relax \let \glossary \relax \unrestored@protected@xdef \@themark {{#1}{#2}}\@temptokena \expandafter {\@themark }\mark {\the \@temptokena }\endgroup \if@nobreak \ifvmode \nobreak \fi \fi`

Answer (score 6):

The primitive `\mark` stores one piece of data. 
The latex commands `\markright` and `\markboth` splits the argument of `\mark` to be able to store two things. So

`\markboth{left 1}{right 1}` does more or less `\mark{{left 1}{right 1}}`

`\markright{right 2}` retrieves the left part of the previous mark and then 
 stores it together with the new right content. So it does (again more or less) `\mark{{left 1}{right 2}}`.

The stored contents can be retrieved (only in the header and footer, at other places the result is not reliable!) with `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`.

As the names indicates the commands retrieve the left and right part respectivly: `\leftmark` gets the left part of the *last* mark on the page, `\rightmark` the right part of the *first* mark on the page (or the last on the previous page).

With normal setups you get these marks

```
 ==== page break, new chapter:
 chapter:     {{chapter}    {   }}
 section1:    {{chapter}    {section1}}
 section2:    {{chapter}    {section2}}
 ==== page break: leftmark: chapter, rightmark: empty

 section3:    {{chapter}    {section3}}
 section4:    {{chapter}    {section4}}
 ==== page break: leftmark: chapter, rightmark: section3
```